# I'm trying to enable SQL Filestream on Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2016 64 bit, Management Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssms, filestream, windows-server, configuration-manager

The machine config is Windows Server 2012, 64 Bit SQL Server 2016, and SQL Server Management Studio 2017. When I use SQL Server Configuration Manager to enable filestream, it gives me an error that I do not know how to get around.

> There was an unknown error applying the FILESTREAM settings. check the
>   parameters are valid. (0x80041008)

Comment: Windows and SQL Server both are 64-bit?

Comment: see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21677430/1387418)

Comment: I've removed the image in your question because it only shows the same error message you have pointed out in your text. You can add it again following [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/225189/revisions) link and clicking rollback button of any of the other edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root Cause?

During October we installed SQL Server 2016 on the server – but the desktop icons were still set to SQL Server 2017. When I used the 2016 Configuration Manager, it seemed to work.

Multiple versions installed on TEST Server:

[image: Multiple SQL versions installed on test server]

Configuration manager on TEST Server with Configuration Manager 2017:

[image: SQL 2017 Configuration Manager]

SQL Server Version on TEST Server:

[image: SQL Version on Test Server]

Using SQL Server 2016 Configuration Manager:

[image]

So basically we were running the wrong version of configuration manager. Also we did a server restart. When I had previously tried to configure it on both 2016, 2017 configuration manager, it didn't work.

Comment: Hi @sam, you should post your solution as an answer to this question

Comment: @JulioNobre thanks, just did that.